# Angular 2 - Debouncing a keyUp event

Tags: angular, lodash, debouncing

How can I debounce a function which gets called on an "keyUp" event?

Here is my code:

**My Function**

```
private handleSearch(searchTextValue: string, skip?: number): void {
    this.searchTextValue = searchTextValue;
    if (this.skip === 0 || typeof skip === "undefined") {
        this.skip = 0;
        this.pageIndex = 1;
    } else {
        this.skip = skip;
    }
    this.searchTextChanged.emit({ searchTextValue: searchTextValue, skip: this.skip, take: this.itemsPerPage });
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'searchquery' | translate }}" id="searchText" #searchText (keyup)="handleSearch(searchText.value)">
```

*Bassically what I'm trying to achieve is that `handleSearch` gets called a few moments after the user stop typing.*

I found out i can use lodash's `_debounce()` for this, but I haven't found out how to put this on my `keyUp` event.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Using RXJS 6 pipe operator:

```
this.subject.pipe(
  debounceTime(500)
).subscribe(searchTextValue => {
  this.handleSearch(searchTextValue);
});
```

---

You could create a rxjs/Subject and call .next() on keyup and subscribe to it with your desired debounceTime.

I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it but it works.

```
private subject: Subject<string> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.subject.debounceTime(500).subscribe(searchTextValue => {
    this.handleSearch(searchTextValue);
  });
}

onKeyUp(searchTextValue: string){
  this.subject.next(searchTextValue);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input (keyup)="onKeyUp(searchText.value)">
```

Comment: how can I pass parameters to `ngOnInit() {
  this.subject.debounceTime(500).subscribe(res => { //do something });
}`?

Comment: You can pass your search query to onKeyUp() then pass it to the .next() and then it would be the 'res' variable in the subscription. Make sure to change the subject from Subject<any> to Subject<string> as you are working with a string. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: and if I have 1 optional parameter? should i put them in an object? In the OP I rely on `searchTextValue` and `skip` which is optional

Comment: I edited it again. About skip, just create a skip variable in your component and use it in the handleSearch method like this: if(this.skip)

Comment: I missed something in your solution, so srry for the dumb questions about the parameters! It works!

Comment: No problem, don't worry ;)

Comment: Don't forget to import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'

Comment: @Ploppy this is just so so beautiful T_T

Comment: When I try this, I'm also getting a delay on the enter key as well, how to avoid? If they stop typing for 1 second, it's firing correctly, but if I hit enter, it's still taking 1 second to fire. I have (keyup)="keyUpFunction($event);" (enter.keyUp)="enterFunction(event)".. problem is enter is also firing generic keyup.

Answer (score 24):

An Update for Rx/JS 6. 
Using the Pipe Operator.

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.subject.pipe(
      debounceTime(500)
    ).subscribe(searchTextValue => {
      this.handleSearch(searchTextValue);
    });
```

Everything else is the same

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35992325/751200

And article here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html (quite old, but still good).

Basically, you can use an Observable object provided by Angular Forms.

For example, `this.myFormGroup.get("searchText").valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(...)`

If you need to perform an HTTP request when user stops typing, you can place such HTTP call into `switchMap` operator and add it to `pipe` list:

```
this.myFormGroup.get("searchText")
                .valueChanges
                .pipe(debounceTime(500),
                      distinctUntilChanged(), 
                      switchMap((value: string) => {
                          return this.service.getData(value);
                      }))
                .subscribe((valueFromRest) => { ... });
```

The magic in `switchMap` will automatically cancel the previous HTTP request (if it's not completed yet) and start a new one automatically.