# How can i implement debouncing with rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, debouncing

I want to implement debouncing.

Vanilla java script code will look like this

```
onInputChange(ev) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(users => console.log('users', users));
    },700)
  }
```

but i can't find a way to do the same with rxjs in my angular compomonent

*i tried*

i found the `debounceTime` operator but it still makes requests every time. There is no delay of 1000 miliseconds

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
    .subscribe(users => console.log('users', users));
```

Also i tried

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newUser" (input)="onInputChange($event)" [formControl]="newUserControll"/>

   this.newUserControll.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000)
    switchMap(() => interval(1000))).subscribe(x => console.log('x', x))
```

but i get

`',' expected.` error

Comment: Do you actually have a reactive input available? Because that is the thing that needs debouncing. The way you have it now won’t work really.. you’ve already made the http call..

Comment: Yes i have formControl binded, i wanted to prevent calling http requests on every key type in the input... How can i do that after i binded to valueChanges on the formControll ?

Comment: Pipe the debounce in the valuechanges..?

Comment: @MikeOne i edited my question. Can you please see it and tell my where is my mistake ?

Comment: Not sure what the interval does in there. Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991867/angular-2-using-observable-debounce-with-http-get

Comment: I don't see any sense in using ngModel with reactive forms control. You have to use either or.

Answer (score 0):

here is sample code implementing debounceTime

Sample stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tsqwh9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
this.searchControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(2000),
    switchMap(searchTerm => {
      //Make Api call here
      console.log(searchTerm);
      return searchTerm; // Remove this code after implenting api call - This is only temporary line
      return; // return result of api call here
    })
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    // Final api response
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your problem is that you are placing debounce *after* the http call.  You must debounce *before* your http call.

Incorrect Flow:

- value changes -> http call -> debounce

Correct Flow:

- value changes -> debounce -> http call

The correct way to use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) is like this:

```js
  data$ = this.newUserControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    switchMap(userInfo => this.http.get(...))
  );
```

Here's a sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68131866?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo that you can play with.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say on change of input you want to call an API with some debounceTime. In your HTML you need to bind that property to get search text as below.
If you see an error related to ngModel then make sure you have this imported:

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
<input placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchBy"(ngModelChange)="changed.next()" name="searchBy">
```

In your .ts file:

```
public searchBy = '';
public changed = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit() {
   this.changed.debounceTime(300).subscribe(() => {
       this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(users => {
         console.log('users', users))
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: @Debang - i get Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>' error when i try your code

Comment: And why i need to use subject in this case ? Is it not possible only with fomrControll valueChanges ?

Comment: Maybe you are using another version of Angular from what I provided. Then you have to add debounceTime this way: this.changed.pipe(debounceTime(300))