# How do I limit the api calls with exhaust map?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to make exhaustMap to work, but am not able to. I want to be able to limit the number of api calls. Right now when I search and it's loading, and I type in another value in the input, the code makes a new api call. I want to limit this, so that this does not happen.

```
  loadItems = () => {
    const element: any = document.getElementById('type-ahead')

    fromEvent(element, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        map((e: any) => e.target.value),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        exhaustMap(() => interval(1000).pipe(take(10))), // doesnt work, i dont even know why im writing 10 here.
        switchMap(this.requestProducts),
        tap((data: any) => {
          this.page = 1
          this.parsedData = data
          this.onViewPage()
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Using Observable.debounce() with Http.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991867/angular-2-using-observable-debounce-with-http-get)

Comment: no, its still making additional api requests when slow 3g throttle

Comment: well it makes a new API call but that's probably triggered by the merged `interval()` Observable.

Comment: i need to use exhaust map

Comment: may be delte the row: exhaustMap(() => interval(1000).pipe(take(10)), and just increase the debounceTime as 1000 or higher value?

Comment: no thats a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, and you wish to ignore all `keyup` events until the HTTP API request for the current event is completed, you'd need only to switch the `switchMap` with `exhaustMap` and remove the current `exhaustMap`.

```js
loadItems = () => {
  const element: any = document.getElementById('type-ahead')

  fromEvent(element, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      map((e: any) => e.target.value),
      exhaustMap(this.requestProducts.bind(this)),      // <-- use `bind(this)` if you use `this` in `requestProducts()` to denote class member variables
      tap((data: any) => {
        this.page = 1;
        this.parsedData = data;
        this.onViewPage();
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

1. You could find differences b/n different RxJS higher order mapping operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921).
2. Usage of `document.getElementById()` in Angular is discouraged since it would search the entire DOM of the app (and note Angular apps are SPA), instead of looking only in the specific component. There are multiple alternatives:

   - Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965515/6513921)
   - Use template reference variable + `ViewChild` + `ElementRef` + RxJS `fromEvent`.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdxfku?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Edit 1**: Include working example

Comment: hey, its still making additional api calls after 200ms wait time on slow 3g. i only want ONE request.

Comment: Do you want that behavour like in the example from the official documentation of [exhaustMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/exhaustMap) which can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/run?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts ?

Comment: @user14850280: I've included a Stackblitz in the post. It seems to work there, also with reduced `debounceTime` values. If the error still persists for you, you might have to provide more information.